# cometd bayeux can't send message to a specific client

Tags: cometd

```java
//StockPriceEmitter is a "dead loop" thread which generate data, and invoke StockPriceService.onUpdates() to send data.
@Service
public class StockPriceService implements StockPriceEmitter.Listener
{
    @Inject
    private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;
    @Session
    private LocalSession sender;

    public void onUpdates(List<StockPriceEmitter.Update> updates)
    {
        for (StockPriceEmitter.Update update : updates)
        {
            // Create the channel name using the stock symbol
            String channelName = "/stock/" + update.getSymbol().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

            // Initialize the channel, making it persistent and lazy
            bayeuxServer.createIfAbsent(channelName, new ConfigurableServerChannel.Initializer()
            {
                public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel)
                {
                    channel.setPersistent(true);
                    channel.setLazy(true);
                }
            });

            // Convert the Update business object to a CometD-friendly format
            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>(4);
            data.put("symbol", update.getSymbol());
            data.put("oldValue", update.getOldValue());
            data.put("newValue", update.getNewValue());

            // Publish to all subscribers
            ServerChannel channel = bayeuxServer.getChannel(channelName);
            channel.publish(sender, data, null); // this code works fine
            //this.sender.getServerSession().deliver(sender, channel.getId(), data, null); // this code does not work
        }
    }
}
```

this line `channel.publish(sender, data, null); // this code works fine` works fine, now I don't want channel to publish message to all clients subscirbed with it, I want to send to a specific client, so I write this `this.sender.getServerSession().deliver(sender, channel.getId(), data, null);`, but it does not work, browser can't get message.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you spend some time reading the [CometD concepts](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#concepts) page, in particular the [section about sessions](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#concepts_sessions).

Your code does not work because you are sending the message to the *sender*, not to the *recipient*.

You need to pick which remote `ServerSession` you want to send the message to among the many that may be connected to your server, and call `serverSession.deliver(...)` on that remote ServerSession.

How to pick the remote `ServerSession` depends on your application.

For example:

```java
for (ServerSession session : bayeuxServer.getSessions())
{
    if (isAdminUser(session))
        session.deliver(sender, channel.getId(), data, null);
}
```

You have to provide an implementation of `isAdmin(ServerSession)` with your logic, of course.

Note that you don't need to iterate over the sessions: if you happen to know the session id to deliver to, you can do:

```java
bayeuxServer.getSession(sessionId).deliver(sender, channel.getId(), data, null);
```

Also refer to the [CometD chat demo](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#installation_demos) shipped with the CometD distribution, that contain a full fledged example of how to send a message to particular session.